# Cannot resolve `T: serde::Deserialize<'de>` when using Serialize and DeserializeOwned as supertraits

Tags: rust, traits, serde

I want my trait to depend on Serde's:

```
pub trait MyTrait: Serialize + DeserializeOwned {}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    value: T,
}

impl MyTrait for i32 {}
impl MyTrait for MyStruct<i32> {}
```

([full code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e353a4735f71227f0b449fc49681e3d2&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

But I get this error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `T: serde::Deserialize<'de>`
  --> src/main.rs:11:21
   |
11 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: required by `serde::Deserialize`
```

I have no idea what that means in this context. I don't understand how it relates to the [info about E0283](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0283).

(I *think* that `DeserializeOwned` is what I want based on the [Serde lifetimes info](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds), but I can't find anything on "extending" traits, so I might be wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, [avoid putting trait bounds on a `struct`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy/issues/1689). Instead, put the bounds on the `impl` block for the methods that need those bounds:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> MyStruct<T> where T: MyTrait {
    fn do_stuff(&self) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The difference in how the constraints are solved for a `struct` versus an `impl` block is a bit subtle, but suffice to say it's different and this change should make your code work as expected.

Comment: It's confusing to me that this is called 'trait bounds on a struct'. It looks like the bounds are on trait MyTrait... (I actually stumbled upon that discussion but skipped it for that reason).

Comment: @Mark "Trait bounds on a struct" really means "trait bounds on _the type parameters of_ a struct". The constraints that you put on the `MyTrait` should still work fine in this case.